# Can't parse new google urls - HTTP_REFERER doesn't contain parameters anymore

Tags: parsing, url, hash, http-referer

It seems a little odd to my, but although everybody knows about the new google search urls (see [Google using # instead of search? in URL. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122523/google-using-instead-of-search-in-url-why)) no one has a problem with the HTTP_REFERER.

I'm using the referrer to parse the google string for the searchquery (&q= ) but as this is all in a hash-tag it wont be sent to the server and all i get is "http://www.google.de/".

So do you know a way of getting the query the user searched for, befor landing on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to late-2011 Google security changes, this is no longer possible when the search was performed by a signed-in Google user. See:

- http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html
- http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure-accessing.html

Answer (score 1):

Since there are multiple q's in the query string you have to match the "q" parameter globally and take the last one:

`/[?|&|#]q=([^&|^#]+)/ig`

Get rid of "site:" searches (there are others, but I haven't done them)

`/[\+|?|&]?site:([^&|^#])+/g, '');`

Then parse the results.

`/[\w^'\(\)\{\}]+|"[^"]+"/g`

This has been working well for me.

Comment: Actually, there's still some clean up to do afterwards. I've been doing this in javascript without the benefit of negative look ahead. Perhaps someone else can enlighten me?

`query = query.replace(/(\'|")/, '\$1');
query = query.replace(/\+site:(.+)$/, ''); //now done above, but left here for backup
query = query.replace(/^[?|&]q=/, ''); //because the Google search is global this has to be lopped off
query = query.replace(/^&query=/, ''); //ditto for lycos`